# Enabling gzip for external http requests

Tags: wordpress, api, http, local

I have a local env that is not automatically decompressing deflated files. The staging server and the production server seem to be doing it automatically (because the code we have up there is working fine) but on my local machine the request body is still compressed. I had some success using:

```
gzinflate()
```

but I would rather find a solution where my local set up is just closer to the production set up (and don't have to change the code all that much).

p.s. this is a wordpress set up.

Answer (score 0):

K I figured it out. Turns out the issue was that I had just updated my local env to php 7 and enabled x-debug. When doing this I also needed to install something for SOAP and CURL requests (if someone would like to explain further I would be appreciative). Here is the command I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-soap php-curl
```